# Generating a random value, and inserting to the db in php

Tags: php, random, authentication

Alright so I am trying to generate a random value, using random_bytes, tell the user his unique ID, and then insert to the database.

I'm using isset so I tried doing $id = bin2hex(random_bytes(16)) but it generates another ID when the user clicks the Register button, meaning the value he saved is not the one that was inserted to the database.

Basically, a random identifier that is generated for him and he needs to save in order to log in (serves as the username).

Thanks!

I know it's something to do with the isset because the value is generated AFTER the user posts the form but I want to tell him something that was not yet generated. not sure how to do it.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['regbutton'])) {   

$username = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$repeatpw = ($_POST['repeatpw']);

// blah blah validations
// executes a database query and insets the $username variable into the db

HTML - <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
```

Comment: Why does it have to be random? Something wrong with sequential?

Comment: Please show us your code. We can't help if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of users knowing how many others there are.

Comment: Be aware that random_bytes is PHP7. I would advice not to use it yet unless your server runs indeed PHP7.

Comment: Then how about using a sequence and hashing it? People can work it out if they really want, but meh.

Comment: Could work, but why not use a totally random value?

Comment: Use a random value if you like. Just trying to suggest a much simpler option.

Comment: so, use sessions if you want to keep the same generate sequence inserted in db. However, why the need for this? There are simpler ways to go about this. Don't you think this is a tad overkill? why not AI'd column or is that too easy?

Comment: if that value's being lost after, something isn't right. I can't see how that could fail. There's some important tidbits you left out as to what the form looks like exactly and how you're passing it over to PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

// generate a random "username" if you haven't done so yet
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// check for form post
if (isset($_POST['regbutton'])) {   

  // get values from form post
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $repeatpw = $_POST['repeatpw'];

  // blah blah validations
  if ($username != $_SESSION['username']) {
    // user changed the username you showed him
  }
  // blah blah other validations
  // executes a database query and insets the $username variable into the db
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, this actually works! but is there a way to insert the original generated value even if the user changed it client-side? (instead of killing the form and saying to him that he changed it).

Comment: Don't read the username back in from the form; eliminate the $username = $_POST['username'] and the if(...) checking it.  $username remains the value pulled from $_SESSION['username'].

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the security issues of doing that. Thanks a whole lot man, saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate tokens if you use JWT, check out [the JWT library](https://jwt.io/)